# Java paginators

Tags: java, pagination, playframework-2.0

I am writing small web-app with play 2 and java. I have list of entities and now I'm gonna to break them into pages. I take component for pagination from Twitter Bootstrap, make my database query to return pages of entities and.. which way I should use to build page navigator?

I mean the following: for example I have total 20 pages and gonna to show 12-th. I have 5 positions to show per-page buttons. Is there some libs or snippets to generate something like:
1 .. 11 12 13 .. 20. I know this is not too hard, and I have implemented it in my previous project... but having one jar that solve this problem for me would be cool. Is there any some solutions?

Answer (score 4):

I can share you what I have, I'm also using bootstrap

```
package models.helper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pager<T> {

    public List<T> entities;

    public int page;

    public int pages;

    public String urlTemplate;

    public int resultsPerPage;

    public List<Integer> getPageList(){
        List<Integer> pageList = new ArrayList<Integer>(pages);
        for(int i = 1; i<=pages;i++){
            pageList.add(i);
        }
        return pageList;
    }

    public int getPrevious(){
        return page -1;
    }

    public int getNext(){
        return page +1;
    }

    public boolean isCurrent(Integer page){
        return this.page == page - 1;
    }

    public boolean isLast(){
        return page == pages -1;
    }

    public boolean isFirst(){
        return page == 0;
    }

    public String getUrl(Integer page){
        return urlTemplate
                .replace("-1", Integer.toString(resultsPerPage))
                .replace("-2", Integer.toString(page-1));
    }

    public String getNextUrl(){
        if(isLast()){
            return "#";
        }
        return urlTemplate
                .replace("-1", Integer.toString(resultsPerPage))
                .replace("-2", Integer.toString(getNext()));
    }

    public String getPreviousUrl(){
        if(isFirst()){
            return "#";
        }
        return urlTemplate
                .replace("-1", Integer.toString(resultsPerPage))
                .replace("-2", Integer.toString(getPrevious()));
    }
}
```

My service returns one of these objects and in my template I have a pager tag

```
@(pager:models.helper.Pager[_])
<div class="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li class="prev@if(pager.isFirst){ disabled}">
        <a href="@pager.getPreviousUrl">&larr; Previous</a>
    </li>
    @for(page <- pager.getPageList){
    <li @if(pager.isCurrent(page)){class="active"}>
        <a href="@pager.getUrl(page)">@page</a>
    </li>
    }
    <li class="next@if(pager.isLast){ disabled}">
      <a href="@pager.getNextUrl">Next &rarr;</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the template url would be built like this (scala)
first parameter being "resultsPerPage" and second one is the actual "page"

```
pager.urlTemplate = routes.Application.myAction(-1, -2).url
```

the -1 and -2 params are a bit ugly but I haven't found a better solution until now

Comment: Oh, thanks. By the way, what Pager[_] means? Its like java's Pager<?> ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no support for paging in templates as far as I know, however fortunately `Ebean` supports it, so you just to need make a little job in your templates.

Check [Computer database sample application](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database), there the paging is implemented for list of computers (it also uses Twitter Bootstrap, so you just to need copy and paste the code)

Of course you can also find the sample application in the Play version which you downloaded to your computer.

Comment: Thanks,yeah, that helps for a while. I build something like this: << | 1 of 10 | >> but thats not exactly what I want. I still wonder why there is no out-of-box solution. Not in the play framework, nor anywhere else.

Comment: Why do you think it should? Although Play is called a `web` framework that doesn't mean, it should deliver CMS-like widgets and snippets out-of-the box. If devs decided to do that, they would waste their time and overload the framework with hundreds of unnecessary elements. There a bunch of ready-to-use CMS'es which delivers templates and all required widgets, and it's not Play's goal to become one of them.

Comment: BTW if you need to build better paging selector you need to check Ebean's documentation for `PagingList Queries` (chapter 6.7 in the Refference Guide at the page: http://www.avaje.org/ebean/documentation.html)

Comment: I don't say they should, but in my opinion pagination is not something very rare to use. And a few out-of-box tools can simplify developers life. I don't say about generating html layout with javascript controllers or something like this. I just try to found good solution to generate list filled with proper page numbers.

Comment: That's not a Play's goal :) I don't write this cause I want to argue - just I can see what are the choices of the dev-team, I can accept it as I agree with their choices almost always. Although I don't agree anyway I understand your point of view, the one of solution is creating a module containing common 'widget set' and publishing it somewhere _pro publico bono_ but I'm pretty sure that dev team will not be interested about that as they concerns on 'mechanics'. As this is no the part of the framework's tasks it should be also delivered by the community, IMHO

Comment: Em, yeah, you right about that's not a play goal :) maybe its a good idea to spent a bit of my time and make little plugin for dealing with that. Maybe it will be helpfull for somebody else. Thanks for discussion)

Comment: You're welcome :) if you kindly do that please consider adding it to the http://www.playmodules.net , that's the place for it!

Comment: Ach! BTW: PlayModules sources are available at github so you can also check the paging element's use: https://github.com/pvillega/Play-Modules

Comment: And small offtopic question: which tools do you use for working with play2? I found it rather hard to refactor my project using eclipse. Maybe plugins or something like super-cool-vim-configuration exists?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12185/discussion-between-marcus-biesior-biesioroff-and-alex-povar)

Comment: Ok. If I have any success with it I'll publish them.

Comment: @biesior The link to the sample play project is dead.